# LibGDX Dependencies

Tags: import, gradle, libgdx, gradlew

I am attempting to set up LibGDX on a computer at school for CompSci.

The version of the Gradle setup .jar is 1.4.1
The root folder is usually located in the C Drive
The school's network has administrator problems which may lead to problems

The entire process of using the Gradle setup and importing the project goes smoothly. However, once generated, each project (core, desktop) is missing its respective Gradle Dependency (persisted), each of which contains the necessary jar files to use LibGDX classes. The imports won't work as a result. For example,

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;

would have red underlines underneath com.badlogic
It wouldn't be that way if the dependencies managed to load.

My teacher tells me that the school network may have blocked certain features of the Gradle setup preventing it from completely loading the Gradle Dependencies. Are there any ways to fix this or find another way of getting a LibGDX environment onto a school computer?

There may be an alternate solution. I sent over one of the games I made (a jar file) and opened it with Winrar, exposing the class files which are used by LibGDX. Is it possible to have the Eclipse at school to use them?

Answer (score 0):

You can [download the jars here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/releases/).  Then put all the jars in a `libs` folder in your project directory. Then go into your project's build.gradle file and make these changes:

In the `allprojects` block, right after the `repositories` block, add this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

That tells it to include all the jars from your `libs` directory in the build path. And now since you did that, you want to tell it not to look for them on MavenCentral. So in all the other blocks (`core`, `android`, `desktop` etc.), comment out every line that starts with `compile`, **except** for the ones that say `compile project`, such as `compile project(":core")`.